# Select div element with role checkbox using Selenium

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, checkbox

I am new to Selenium and I am learning the basics. I want to select a checkbox on  the page with this python code:

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='checkbox1']").click()
```

Unfortunately this approach does not work. I get an error from Selenium saying that function click() does not exist for the webelement. The div element in the html page is defined like this:

```
    <div role="checkbox" id="checkbox1"></div>
```

What other functions exists (similar to click()) to select the checkbox.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a checkbox. It looks like a `<div>`. A checkbox is `<input type="checkbox">`.

Comment: provide more of the html. As noted above this is a div, which doesn't have a clickable action.

Comment: @DMart I'm not sure what you mean... you can click a DIV.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the full error message. Your code should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

On the HTML you provided the element is a `div` not an `input` but that really does not matter. 
You should be able to do this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('checkbox1').click()
```

You mentioned you were getting an error when clicking the element. 
Could you share that error? 
Im guessing that it must be something like `Element not clickable at point [...]` or `Element not visible`

If thats the case, make sure that the element is displayed in the view port before you interact with it.
You can use [Action chains](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) or javascript to move to the element.
Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936849/selenium-webdriver-checkbox-element-is-not-clickable)