# Selenium Click is not happening for checkbox within label element

Tags: selenium

I am trying to click a checkbox on my webpage and the DOM is given below:

```
<label class='checkbox-module-container'>
<input type='checkbox' class='dummyclass'>
```

When I tried to click on the input checkbox, I am getting 'Element not clickable' exception.

Tried with JavaScript executor also but no luck.

Is there any workaround to make element click on those elements which are overlapped?

Comment: Dom will be <label class='module-container'><input type='checkbox'></label>

Comment: Check this thread please:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936849/selenium-webdriver-checkbox-element-is-not-clickable

Answer (score 2):

If the **HTML DOM** is

```
<label class='checkbox-module-container'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='dummyclass'>
    </input>
</label>
```

then you can try to click on it like below.

There are 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//label[contains(@class,'checkbox-module-container')]//child::input[@type='checkbox']
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(@class,'checkbox-module-container')]//child::input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[contains(@class,'checkbox-module-container')]//child::input[@type='checkbox']"))).click();
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(@class,'checkbox-module-container')]//child::input[@type='checkbox']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
WebElement button  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(@class,'checkbox-module-container')]//child::input[@type='checkbox']"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(button).click().build().perform();
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.